# SoapAction header not understood - consuming a asmx web service - using custom binding - dot net core 3.1 c# app

Tags: c#, .net-core, soap, .net-core-3.1

I was having requirement to consume a https asmx service exposing methods via both basicHttpBinding and custom binding. I am able to get response when i use basicHttpBinding. However with custom binding i am getting following error.

**SoapAction header not understood.**

I generated the service proxy using svcutil.exe and injected the dependency in my startup.cs file as follows.
Binding in proxy file by svcutil.exe

```
<customBinding>
                <binding name="MyServicesSoap12">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
 </customBinding>
```

Code in startup.cs

```
.ConfigureServices((ctxt, service) =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped<IMyServicesSoap12>(provider => {
                //var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport);
                var binding = new CustomBinding();
                var msgVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12);
                binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(msgVersion, System.Text.Encoding.Default));
                binding.Elements.Add(new HttpsTransportBindingElement() { AllowCookies = true, MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue, MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue });
                var endPoint = new EndpointAddress("https://someservice.asmx");
                var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyServicesSoap12>(binding, endPoint);
                var client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
                return client;
            });
                           
          }
```

Then i did constructor injection of IMyServicesSoap12 in myLogic class.

Here is my consumer code.

```
var Response = await _myService.MethodAsync(requestVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent almost 4-5 hours on this searching for answers. I didn't use Add Connected Service option initially as suggested in https://joshuachini.com/2017/07/13/calling-a-soap-service-from-asp-net-core-or-net-core/

Finally I saw the auto generated code which comes when you use Add Connected Service option. All i was missing was a tiny item. Doesn't it always boils down to one tiny mistake!

I was missing optional argument for `AddressingVersion` while setting up message version.

Previous -

```
var msgVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12);
```

Changed -

```
var msgVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap12,AddressingVersion.None);
```

That fixed the issue for me. Thought of sharing and saving some hours for fellow devs here.